# Is there a way to select range in Google scripts based on a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I started out using google scripts and sheets after departing from excel.

In excel, when you want to select a particular range using a variable, the formula in the macro will be
`Range("C1:F" & lastrow).select`
where `lastrow` is the variable that you have previously named.

I cannot find an equivalent formula or script that can do the same in google scripting.

Basically all I want is to select a particular range to copy, but because the data row will vary, I want to select only the used rows rather than just the entire page.

Comment: Hey @lysa0 were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for your help, it was critical in helping me to find the right direction!

I managed to cobble together a code that basically mirrors the excel code of selecting the rows and columns that i need.
For some reason, I realised like google scripts are case sensitive but excel vb is not, so it is another thing that I did have to watch out for.

Basically, this is the equivalent of excel's macro for:

```
Sheets("MySheet").select
lastrow = Range("O99999").End(XLUp).row
Range("K1:V" & lastrow).select
```

Here is my code:

```
function zzz1() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MySheet');
var lastrow = sheet.getRange("O"+(sheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
var printrange = sheet.getRange("K1:V" + lastrow)
printrange.activate()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using formulas

You can use the [`=INDIRECT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function, along with Google Sheets concatenation.

> Returns a cell reference specified by a string.

As an example, given the following "Student info" sheet:

[image]

You can get the first three students by using `=INDIRECT("Student info!A2:B"&B1)` from another sheet in the same Spreadsheet, as seen below:

[image]

### Using Google Apps Script

You can use the [`getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method of the [`Class Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), along with JavaScript concatenation to obtain a range of your choice. As an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Student info');
  var lastRow = 4;

  var studentRange = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastRow);

  Logger.log(studentRange.getValues());
}
```

This will obtain the range `A2:B4` and print its values using the [`Logger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging).

Alternatively, you can also use the [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) variation of the method. The usage, in this case, would be as follows:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Student info');
  var lastRow = 4;

  var studentRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 2);

  Logger.log(studentRange.getValues());
}
```

### Extra

In order to import data from **another Spreadsheet** you can use the [`=IMPORTRANGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) function. For a setup such as the one above but obtaining the data from a different Spreadsheet, the function could be used as follows:

[image]